# How can I use map operator with for loop?

Tags: python, django

I have a function that returns a list of the total counts. I want to use the map but don't know how I can use it.

Here is my function:

```
def get_bought_passenger_count(self):
    c = 0
    for book in self.bookings.all():
        c += book.passenger_count
    return c
```

I want to use this with the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's neccessary.

you are just constantly adding terms, so it's just a `sum` and it doesn't require to use the `map()` function, you could use the builtin `sum()` function, and a generator:

```
def get_bought_passengers(self):
    return sum(book.passenger_count for book in self.bookings.all())
```

as @Lecdi said in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum together with list comprehension

```
def get_bought_passengers(self):
    return sum([book.passenger_count for book in self.bookings.all()])
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get the count of objects in queryset You can use `count()` Function...

```py
MyModel.objects.all().count() # return the Number of Objects in the Queryset 
# count is faster than sum
```